Select foreign language for all cells in one column of table?
I’d like to write a glossary table, with (say) English words in the first column and Swedish in the second — similar to what’s described in this question.
Adding \foreignlanguage{swedish}{…} in every row is very verbose and repetitive.  A slight improvement is to write a macro for each row, like \newcommand{\engswe}[2]{#1 & \foreignlanguage{swedish}{#2} \\} — which requires rewriting the table content to use this macro throughout, making it somewhat less readable and flexible.  Is there a way to achieve this without having to rewrite/annotate the table contents at all? That is: Is there a way to specify in the initial table specification that all cells in some column should be wrapped with \foreignlanguage{…}{…}, or switched to a given language in some other way?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\begin{document}

Desired output:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
berry & \foreignlanguage{swedish}{b"ar} \\
bear & \foreignlanguage{swedish}{bj"orn}
\end{tabular}

My best approach so far, using newcommand to abstract table rows:

\newcommand{\engswe}[2]{#1 & \foreignlanguage{swedish}{#2} \\}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\engswe{berry}{b"ar}
\engswe{bear}{bj"orn}
\end{tabular}

Desired simple source, table content unmarked:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
berry & b"ar \\
bear & bj"orn
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


You can either use collcell or just array. The first solution has the advantage that you can use \SE anywhere, not just in tables.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell} % for the simplest solution

\newcommand{\SE}[1]{\foreignlanguage{swedish}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Desired output:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
berry & \foreignlanguage{swedish}{b"ar} \\
bear & \foreignlanguage{swedish}{bj"orn}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Desired simple source, table content unmarked:

\begin{tabular}{l>{\collectcell\SE}l<{\endcollectcell}}
berry & b"ar \\
bear & bj"orn
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Equivalent solution

\begin{tabular}{l>{\begin{otherlanguage*}{swedish}}l<{\end{otherlanguage*}}}
berry & b"ar \\
bear & bj"orn
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Not so good solution

\begin{tabular}{l>{\selectlanguage{swedish}}l}
berry & b"ar \\
bear & bj"orn
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Why is the last solution not so good? Look in the .aux file to see
\babel@aux{english}{}
\babel@aux{swedish}{}
\babel@aux{english}{}
\babel@aux{swedish}{}
\babel@aux{english}{}

At each call of \selectlanguage{swedish} two annotations are written out, plus one at the start. If you have, say, 100 cells, you'd fill the .aux file with more than 200 annotations that have to be evaluated at begin document and at end document for no purpose.
And each such annotation will make one in the .toc, .lof and .lot file as well. Say that you have the table of contents, the list of figures and the list of tables. You'll end up doing \select@language more than 600 times.
To the contrary, neither \foreignlanguage nor otherlanguage* will write out such annotations.
As a general rule, \selectlanguage{<lang>} should only be used when an extensive part of the document is written in a different language, say at the level of a chapter, when the grouping introduced by the otherlanguage environment could lead to poorer performance.
For less extensive parts, such as an abstract, one can use the otherlanguage environment, which also sets the tags for the different language (for instance, \abstractname).
For shorter parts where just the typographic conventions in the different language are needed (such as shorthands and hyphenation), the otherlanguage* environment is the best choice. For sentences or parts of sentences, the \foreignlanguage command is a convenient shorthand for otherlanguage*.

You can use the array package to insert any command at the start of each cell in a column, so in this case
\begin{tabular}{l >{\selectlanguage{swedish}}l}
berry & b"ar \\
bear & bj"orn
\end{tabular}


Thanks — I was exactly hoping for some mechanism like this, but hadn’t managed to find this!  This answer doesn’t quite work as written (at least for me), since \foreignlanguage would need to receive the cell content as an argument, rather than just being prepended — but changing the table spec to {l >{\selectlanguage{swedish}}l<{\selectlanguage{english}}} works just as desired.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine oops sorry I'll fix as you suggest

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine you don't need the < clause though as the cell is a group so setting the language to english at the end does nothing

Look in the ,aux file…

@egreg but that would mean I had to run the code to generate one:-) I see you get the aux file marker each time, hmm
